# Talend - Regroup two paths in only one

Tags: java, web-services, architecture, jobs, talend

Im creating a job which call two web-services. I must manage error case.

The use case :

1. User send his information (user1, user2) (tRestRequest)
2. The job call the 1st webService and get information (tRestClient)
3. The job call the 2nd webService and get information (tRestClient)
4. The job merge information and build the response (tXMLMap)
5. The job respond with information (tRestResponse)

My problem : tRestClient have two output : OK and ERROR. How merge this path to continue the job ?

I attach a screen with, in blue arrow, the ideal situation (but Talend doesn't accept that). If there are a problem with my first webservice, I must to continue the job.

I tried to delete the error output but if an exception is thrown in tRestClient, the job crash.

Someone have a idea ? Thanks for you support !

John

[image: Idyllic situation]

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem recently where I needed to run one of a number of tasks and then, whichever task I had run I wanted to do the same processing on the output flow. I found that you could trigger a component from multiple places using the Component OK trigger. So I stuck a tSetGlobalVar on the end of each flow that had to be merged together, and then used the Component OK trigger from all of them to trigger a tFixedFlowInput which reconstructed the flow from the global variables I had set up and continued my processing from there. It is working fine for me. You could probably use tFlowToIterate if you preferred, but you would have to uncheck the "Use default (key, value) in global variable" check box so you could specify the same global variable names in all of them.

Comment: Yeah, I used a hack like this, with tSetGlobalVar on each path and  "if" event at the beginning of my job.

But I have found a better solution : using subJobs and push data with bufferOutput.

Thanks for your response !